# How to plot a 3D graph in python when x and y have different dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, finance

I am trying to plot the error values for different values of the parameters K1 and N1 respectively. My values of K1 lie in the range 20 to 300, with increments of 10 at each step. The values of N1 range from 3 to 31, with increments of 1 at each step. The value of error is calculated for each combination of (K1,N1). I want to plot the error value for each of the different combinations of (K1,N1).

Here is my code:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as si
from scipy import integrate
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
r=0.03
S0=100
T=1
#short maturity
u1=1/5
mu=r
strike=100
sigma=0.3
K1=20
K=[]
N=[]
E=[]
d1= (np.log(S0 / strike) + (r + 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * (T)) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T))
d2 = (np.log(S0 /strike) + (r - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * (T)) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T))
call = (S0 * si.norm.cdf(d1, 0.0, 1.0) - strike * np.exp(-r * (T)) * si.norm.cdf(d2, 0.0, 1.0))
for N1 in range(3,31,1):
    for K1 in range(20,300,10):
        def f(x):
            d= (np.log(x/strike) + (r + 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * (T-u1)) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T-u1))
            W1=(si.norm.pdf(d))/(x*sigma*np.sqrt(T-u1))
            d11= (np.log(S0/x) + (r + 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * (u1)) / (sigma * np.sqrt(u1))
            d22 = (np.log(S0/x) + (r - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * (u1)) / (sigma * np.sqrt(u1))
            call1 = (S0 * si.norm.cdf(d11, 0.0, 1.0) - x* np.exp(-r * (u1)) * si.norm.cdf(d22, 0.0, 1.0))
            return W1*call1
        hedge=integrate.fixed_quad(f, 0,K1,n=N1)
        error=np.log(np.abs(hedge[0]-call))
        print("The log error for",str(N1),"quadrature points and K1=",str(K1)," is:", error)
        K.append(K1)
        E.append(error)
    N.append(N1)
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_title("Error in option value")
ax.set_xlabel("Value of K1")
ax.set_ylabel("Number of quadrature points")
ax.set_zlabel("Log error")
ax.plot(K, N, E)
plt.savefig("some.png",dpi=200)
plt.show()
```

The output shows the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-64d11f194fa4> in <module>
     42 ax.set_ylabel("Number of quadrature points")
     43 ax.set_zlabel("Log error")
---> 44 ax.plot(K, N, E)
     45 plt.savefig("some.png",dpi=200)
     46 plt.show()

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib-3.4.0rc3-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py in plot(self, xs, ys, zdir, *args, **kwargs)
   1570         zs = np.broadcast_to(zs, np.shape(xs))
   1571 
-> 1572         lines = super().plot(xs, ys, *args, **kwargs)
   1573         for line in lines:
   1574             art3d.line_2d_to_3d(line, zs=zs, zdir=zdir)

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib-3.4.0rc3-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1603         """
   1604         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1605         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1606         for line in lines:
   1607             self.add_line(line)

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib-3.4.0rc3-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in __call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    313                 this += args[0],
    314                 args = args[1:]
--> 315             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    316 
    317     def get_next_color(self):

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib-3.4.0rc3-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs)
    499 
    500         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 501             raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
    502                              f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
    503         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (784,) and (28,)
```

I do not understand how to rectify this. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

plt.lpot only plots 2d graphs, you can use [plot_surface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html?highlight=plot_surface#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_surface) instead, just replace:

```
ax.plot(K, N, E)
```

by:

```
ax.plot_surface(K, N, E)
```

Edit:

plot_surface takes 2D arrays as input, you can use [plot3D](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html?highlight=plot_surface#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot3D) or [plot_trisurf](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html?highlight=plot_surface#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot3D)

Comment: I tried the same. It is giving me the following error:

Comment: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: Yes see my edit for that

Comment: When i am doing plot3D it gives the output as: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (784,) and (28,)

Comment: Can you try doing `k, n = np.meshgrid(K, N)` then do a plot3D

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have rectified it